# Google Admin SDK authentication with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite, service-accounts

My team is currently developing an application to list my company's domain users in GCP, using the Admin SDK, for onboarding and offboarding purposes.

We're using a service account to do this and we've have added the **admin.directory.user.readonly** scope, in the Google Admin's advanced settings, to it. The Admin SDK API is activated and we can see the service account in the Credentials area.

When we invoke the https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users endpoint with the parameters *viewType=domain_public* and *domain=[our domain]*, while using an access token generated with [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l), we receive the following message:

```
{
   "error": {
       "errors": [
           {
               "domain": "global",
               "reason": "forbidden",
               "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
           }
       ],
       "code": 403,
       "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
}
```

Could there be any domain restriction being applied that we don't have vision of?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and impersonate one of your users if you want to authorize using a service account. The service account itself isn't part of the G Suite account, so you must impersonate a user who is part of the G Suite account in order to access the directory of that account.

oauth2l doesn't support domain-wide delegation, if I recall correctly.